# c++ - When I create a template I try to use it but get an error(C2668) and IntelliSense error

Tags: c++, templates

i create a template but get error.

the template and main (this code in one cpp file):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T> 
void swap(T& x, T& y);

template<class T> 
void swap(T& x, T& y){
    T temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main(){
int n1 = 10, n2 = 5;

cout << "number before swap: num1= " << n1 << " num2= " << n2 << endl;
swap(n1, n2);//compilation error
cout << "number after swap: num1= " << n1 << " num2= " << n2 << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

error:

```
Error   1   error C2668: 'std::swap' : ambiguous call to overloaded function    
c:\projects\template\main.cpp   42  1   Template
2   IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "swap" 
matches the argument list:
        function template "void swap(T &x, T &y)"
        function template "void std::swap(_Ty &, _Ty &)"
        argument types are: (int, int)  c:\Projects\Template\main.cpp   43  
2   Template
```

why i get error i don't understand because all look fine.
thank's for the help.

thank's.

Comment: it appears that `std::swap` is declared inside `<iostream>`. Which is not a requirement but which is completely valid.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `using namespace std;`. Because of this, the compiler has no way of knowing whether the line `swap(n1, n2);` means to use `std::swap` or your custom `swap`. You can resolve the ambiguity by explicitly specifying the namespace to use. You can use `::` to specify the global namespace, which is where you defined your `swap` function. Try:

```
int main()
{
    int n1 = 10, n2 = 5;

    cout << "number before swap: num1= " << n1 << " num2= " << n2 << endl;
    ::swap(n1, n2);
    cout << "number after swap: num1= " << n1 << " num2= " << n2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, the real solution here is to remove `using namespace std;`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for an explanation of why this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have a `using namespace std` declaration and implement your own swap function, you can change your function name to start with an uppercase, `Swap()`. Since C++ is case-sensitive, that will avoid the clash, and therefore the ambiguity. It's better practice to use the Standard Library version, however.